# Cosa significa "cordino" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Io mi ero alzato, stavo alle spalle del tuo avversario. Questi ti lanciò due lire al di sopra del **cordino**. Anche altri, che avevano scommesso, ti pagarono. L’avanguardista disse: «Te li darò domani». «Me li dài adesso perché li hai» rispondesti.

Si tratta di una scena in cui stanno giocando a ping-pong.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cordino) ho trovato che "cordino" è una

> Corda sottile o rinforzata per varî usi.

Tuttavia non riesco a capirne il significato in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Se stanno giocando a ping-pong il cordino potrebbe essere il filo teso che sostiene la rete che divide le due parti del tavolo da ping-pong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dal momento che stanno giocando a ping-pong il cordino potrebbe benissimo essere il filo teso che sostiene la rete che divide le due parti del tavolo da ping-pong.